# Can't fields be generic in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, field

I'm reading a book "C# in depth" by Jon Skeet and there is a part that confuses me:

> Methods and nested types can be generic, but all of the following have
> to be nongeneric:
>
> - Fields
> - Properties
> - Indexers
> - Constructors
> - Events
> - Finalizers

I tested and fields (a variable in a class) can be generic, am I not understanding? It makes me doubt about the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes and methods can introduce a new generic type parameter, the others in that list can be defined based on that type parameter, but cannot introduce a new one.

This is all fine;

```cs
class ClassName<T>{
    private T FieldName;
    private T PropertyName { get; set; }
    private R GenericMethod<R>(T t, R r) { ... }
}
```

But not;

```cs
class ClassName{
    private T FieldName<T>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why it said: "For type members, it’s slightly more confusing; some members may look like
they’re generic because they use other generic types. Remember that a declaration is
generic only if it introduces new type parameters."